# charts.js from session var, flicker effect

Tags: php, chart.js, session-variables

My charts loaded via ajax call looks just fine. Currently, whenever user refresh the page, data are loaded from DB server. As those graphs are quite massive, I thought about using SESSION var to store the charts and speed up loading time (all charts are loaded at the same time). Finally, I achieved the goal however I encountered small issue.

Whenever HTML + JS code is served from $_SESSION var, the chart is presented but with no animation effect. In addition flicker effect is visible (scaling). I solved that by setting responsive to false, but this caused issue with labels, being too small to be accepted.

I tried .destroy() option but with no luck (the same flicker effect) :

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctw, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chart_data,
    options: chart_options
});

myChart.destroy();

var myChart = new Chart(ctw, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chart_data,
    options: chart_options
});
```

Is there any way I can force animation to kick in (regardless if the chart comes from $_SESSION or not) and do not loss responsiveness?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If myChart.destroy() not working. Try myChart.update().

Try update like this:

```
var myChartData = myChart.data; // need to store in variable first

myChartData = chart_data; // chart_data from $_SESSION var
myChart.data = myChartData;

myChart.update();
```

Good luck.